# How do I limit the results group wise in a select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

emp table
[image: Table 1 in the database]

Question is : **List the employees and manager belonging to the same department and has the maximum salary difference between them**

I could get till the following results:
[image: Its shows department wise sorted list in descending order of difference in salary of manager and employee of the same department.]

My Query:

```sql
select dno dn,emp_n,abs(mgr_sal - e_sal) diff, emp_n e_n, mgr_n m_n 
from (select m.deptno dno,m.sal mgr_sal,e.sal e_sal,e.ename emp_n,m.ename mgr_n
      from emp e join emp m on e.mgr = m.empno 
      where e.deptno = m.deptno ) dt order by dno,diff desc;
```

As per the question I need only maximum difference grouped department wise results. From the above results I need only rows with maximum salary difference between an employee and manager both belonging to the same department from each department.
i.e.,

| dn | diff | emp_name | mgr_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2550 | CLARK | KING |
| 20 | 2200 | SMITH | FORD |
| 30 | 1900 | JAMES | BLAKE |

The problem is getting the employee and managers' name from the derived table. The group function always returns the first row values which coincidentally for dept no. 10 and 20's row employee and manager are <Clark, King> and <Smith, Ford> and in dept no. 30 its <Allen, Blake>(that's how I found out the results are wrong!).
How do I get the employee and their manager having maximum salary difference belonging to the same department?

Comment: Text is more useful than images.

Comment: I edited the question, is this enough?

Comment: Why: "Table 1 in database" ?   I do mean the **name** of the table is missing.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The task is a bit unclear. Obviously manager is a job (`job = 'MANAGER'`), but it is also a function, e.g. an analyst can function as a clerk's manager via `mgr`. Which of the two is meant here? Do we look at the job MANAGER or do we look at an employee's manager  in the same department or do we look at someone's manager in the same department? To me it sounds like we shall be looking at the job column, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 2):

After doing a self join to retrieve the employee and manager name like you did, you can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` by partitioning on `deptno` and ordering by `diff` descendent.

```
WITH emps_and_mgrs AS (
    SELECT 
        employees.deptno,
        managers.sal - employees.sal    AS diff,
        employees.ename                 AS emp_name,
        managers.ename                  AS mgr_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY deptno 
            ORDER BY managers.sal - employees.sal DESC)         AS rank
    FROM 
        tab employees
    INNER JOIN 
        tab managers
    ON 
        employees.mgr = managers.empno AND employees.deptno = managers.deptno
)
SELECT 
    deptno,
    diff,
    emp_name,
    mgr_name
FROM 
    emps_and_mgrs
WHERE 
    rank = 1
```

Comment: You cannot use an alias defined in a select clause in that same select clause. And as there can be more than one employee with the same salary, I'd recommend `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` here: `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY employees.deptno ORDER BY managers.sal - employees.sal DESC)`. As to the task itself: It is not clear from the task, whether we are supposed to look at an amployee's direct manager or at managers in the department in general. I've made an according comment under the request.

Comment: Apparently window functions are evaluated after aliasing assignment: this query was tested in a reproduced environment. Agreed on RANK/DENSE_RANK.

Comment: Using the alias thus doesn't work in MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3dd6b250412fc9ea24cf11fd588c4950. (It doesn't work in PostgreSQL,Oracle, and SQL Server either.)

Comment: Found why it's working: I'm using MariaDB instead of MySQL, nevermind.